# What is the origin of Chandrashekhara Ashtakam?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, scripture, puranas, padma-purana

[Chandrashekhara Ashtakam](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/chandra8.html?lang=sa) is believed to be created by Sage Marakandeya. It is believed that when Yama is trying to take life of Sage Marakandeya, then he had sung this Stotram and thus Lord Shiva has saved him.

I have read this story in [Padma Purana, Uttara Khanda downloaded from vedpuran.net website](https://vedpuran.net/). But this story is not found in any other version of Padma Purana. So, I think the Padma Purana which I have is interpolated. That's why **I am looking for the source of Chandrashekhara Ashtakam**.

Comment: Even i searched for Chandrasekhar Ashtakam. I couldn't even find story of Yama, Markandeya and  Shiva. I even want to know what Shiva exactly said to Markandeya parents regarding life span of Markandeya.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes I have read your conversation in chat room and then my focus went on Padma Purana which I have read in Hindi. Then I have searched in multiple other versions of Padma Purana but didn't found. I have also asked one version of it from Tezz but it also doesn't contain the story.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have critical editions of Puranas. I think only Mahabharata has critical edition.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That's quite interesting! I wonder how the story of Markandeya Rishi got so popular if it ain't present in any scripture.

Comment: @Chinmay I think what @ Triyugi is saying is that the Chandrashekara ashtakam is interpolated, not the story of Markandeya.

Comment: @Surya Yeah but TheDestroyer is saying that the story of Markandeya is not present in any puranas. Even on wikipedia page, it doesn't mention the name of scripture, it just states - "One legend relates the story..."

Comment: @Surya The whole story is not present in Padma Purana.

Comment: @Surya The story of Markandeya being rescued from Yama by Shiva isn't mentioned in any Puranas, it's just folklore.  The only similar story that does have a basis in scripture is the king Shweta being rescued from Yama by Shiva, described in the Skanda Purana.

Comment: @Keshav Are you completely sure? How did it become so popular if it does not exist in even a single scripture? And does it mean that the chapter that Triyugi is asking about is the only thing about Markandeya?

Comment: @Keshav There is a very small reference to Markandeya's story in the Bhagavatam albeit without mentioning his name over [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/10/15)

Comment: @Surya Well, that could be a reference to the story of Shweta.  But the way, I subsequently learned that while the story of Shiva rescuing Markandeya from Yama has no scriptural basis, the Narasimha Purana describes **Vishnu** rescuing Markandeya from Yama.